# Use DateOperators.Month.withTimezone correctly in a spring data mongo aggregation

Tags: mongodb, spring-data-mongodb

I have a set of mongodb documents like these

```
    * 1 */
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("613b21fe2e57a07bbacc18da"),
    "date" : ISODate("2021-07-31T22:00:00.000Z"),
    "initiativeId" : "613b17332e57a07bbacc164d",
    "studentClass" : "3A",
    "instituteId" : "60c89b7c1442725ff813733c",
    "values" : [ 
        {
            "mode" : "piedi",
            "distanceKm" : 12.2,
            "studentNumber" : 4
        }, 
        {
            "mode" : "pedibus",
            "distanceKm" : 4.2,
            "studentNumber" : 2
        }
    ]
}

/* 2 */
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("613b21fe2e57a07bbacc18dc"),
    "date" : ISODate("2021-09-06T22:00:00.000Z"),
    "initiativeId" : "613b17332e57a07bbacc164d",
    "studentClass" : "5C",
    "instituteId" : "60c89b7c1442725ff813733c",
    "values" : [ 
        {
            "mode" : "moto",
            "distanceKm" : 10.0,
            "studentNumber" : 1
        }
    ]
}
```

I'm using MongoDB 4.4.

I want to reproduce following working mongodb query using Spring Data Mongo (v2.2.5)

```
db.initiativeRecord.aggregate([
{ $addFields: { month: { year: {$year : "$date"}, 
                         month: {$month : { date: "$date", timezone: "Europe/Rome"}} 
                       } } },
{ $unwind : "$values" },
{ $group : { _id: {d: "$month", mode: "$values.mode"}, distance: {$sum: "$values.distanceKm" } } }
])
```

This is the Spring data mongo code

```
  List<AggregationOperation> operations = new ArrayList<>();
    operations.add(Aggregation.unwind("values"));
    
       
    ProjectionOperation subProject = Aggregation.project("values")
        .and(DateOperators.Month.monthOf("date").withTimezone(Timezone.valueOf("Europe/Rome"))).as("month")
        .and(DateOperators.Year.year("$date")).as("year");
    operations.add(subProject);

    GroupOperation group = Aggregation.group("distance","year", "month","values.mode").sum("values.distanceKm").as("distance");
    project = project.andExpression("_id.mode").as("mode")
        .andExpression("_id.month").as("month")
        .andExpression("_id.year").as("year");

    operations.add(group);
    operations.add(project);
```

The problem is the use of timezone attribute in $month function

when I try to add this

```
DateOperators.Month.monthOf("date").withTimezone(Timezone.valueOf("Europe/Rome"))
```

execution throws following exception

```
Command failed with error 16006 (Location16006): 'can't convert from BSON type object to Date' on server localhost:40393. The full response is {"ok": 0.0, "errmsg": "can't convert from BSON type object to Date", "code": 16006, "codeName": "Location16006"}
```

When I remove withTimezone part

```
DateOperators.Month.monthOf("date")
```

execution doesn't throw the exception

I don't understand how to use withTimezone correctly in my code

Comment: `NOTE: Support for timezones in aggregations Requires MongoDB 3.6 or later` tells the [Javadoc](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/mongodb/docs/current/api/org/springframework/data/mongodb/core/aggregation/DateOperators.Timezone.html).

Comment: I'm using MongoDb 4.4

Comment: You are using ```$addFields``` in the query but ```Aggregation.project``` in code. Can you please check with ```Aggregation.addFields``` in the code?

Comment: I'm using spring data mongodb 2.2.5, Aggregation.addFields has been introduced since 3.0.0 https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/mongodb/docs/3.2.4/api/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a lot of tests I can answer the question myself. I decided to do it as future documentation for everybody.

The code is correct and works well with MongoDb 4.4.
Spring data mongodb 2.2.5 supports `DateOperators.Month.month.withTimeZone` correctly.

The exception was thrown by `de.flapdoodle.embed.mongo` (version 2.2.0 in my case) (an embedded mongo db) I use for tests.